# HTML Move Canvas object with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Is it possible to attach onclick event to move the object `img` left, down and right.

The button are placeholder , the sequence are left,down and right.

I'm facing two issue:-
 1. My width is `500px`, even when I drew it at `250px`. It doesn't center .
 2. I've tried multiple ways to add the onclick function to `-/+` the `y-axis` and `x-axis` .

I've even tried to adapt to this code :
http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-move-an-object-on-the-html5-canvas/

But no luck either.
Is there something i missing? I've checked on google mostly are keyevent handler.

JSBIN:

http://jsbin.com/wuseguvuka/2/edit?html,css,output

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */
#main {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}   
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-left: 2.275%;
    padding-right: 2.275%;
}
/* Header */
header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logoPlaceholder span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .logoPlaceholder2 span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    background-color: rgba(237,237,237,1.00);
    width: 259px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 259px;
    clear: both;
}
header .profileHeader h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
header .profileHeader h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
hr {
    background-color: rgba(208,207,207,1.00);
    height: 1px;
}
header .profileHeader p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Media query for Mobile devices*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 285px) and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Header */
#main {

width:100%;

}   
header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}   
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    display: inline-block;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
header .profileHeader p {
    text-align: justify;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;

    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Media Query for Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Header */
header {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Desktops and laptops  */
@media only screen and (min-width:1025px) {
/* Header */
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}



.wrapper {
   display: table;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.container {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.canvas-container {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 1024px;
   min-width: 120px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}



}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>About Page template By Adobe Dreamweaver CC</title>
<link href="AboutPageAssets/styles/aboutPageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/montserrat:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>


function load() {
 var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/75x150";
img.onload = function () {

    context.drawImage(img, 250, 0);
}

}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="load();">
<!-- Header content -->
<header>
  <div class="profileLogo"> 
    <!-- Profile logo. Add a img tag in place of <span>. -->
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Name :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Attempts :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Score :</span></p>
  </div>
  <section>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="canvas-container">

      <canvas id="main" width="500px" height="250px"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
  <!-- Links to Social network accounts -->
  <aside class="socialNetworkNavBar">
    <div style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" >

      </div>
    <div id="left" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" > </div>
    <div id="down" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input id="right"  type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" >
 </div>

  </aside>
</header>
<!-- content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes!**

It is absolutely possible. Here is how you could achieve that ...

```js
function load() {
   var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");
   var left = document.getElementById('left');
   var down = document.getElementById('down');
   var right = document.getElementById('right');
   var imgLoaded = false;
   var posX = 250;
   var posY = 0;
   var snap = 10;

   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() {
      imgLoaded = true;
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);
   };
   img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/75x150";

   // left button click
   left.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posX = posX - snap;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);
   };
 
   // down button click
   down.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY + snap;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);
   };
 
   // right button click
   right.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posX = posX + snap;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);
   };

}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */

#main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-left: 2.275%;
    padding-right: 2.275%;
}
/* Header */

header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logoPlaceholder span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .logoPlaceholder2 span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1.00);
    width: 259px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 259px;
    clear: both;
}
header .profileHeader h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146, 146, 146, 1.00);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
header .profileHeader h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146, 146, 146, 1.00);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
hr {
    background-color: rgba(208, 207, 207, 1.00);
    height: 1px;
}
header .profileHeader p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146, 146, 146, 1.00);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
/* Media query for Mobile devices*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 285px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* Header */
    
    #main {
        width: 100%;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    header .profilePhoto {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    header .profileHeader {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    header .profileHeader p {
        text-align: justify;
    }
    header .socialNetworkNavBar {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 60px;
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
    }
    header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 23px;
    }
}
/* Media Query for Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* Header */
    
    header {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    header .profilePhoto {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin-right: 3%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    header .profileHeader {
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 7%;
    }
    header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
        width: 74px;
        height: 74px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 23px;
    }
}
/* Desktops and laptops  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    /* Header */
    
    header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    header .profilePhoto {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin-right: 3%;
    }
    header .profileHeader {
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 10%;
    }
    header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
        width: 74px;
        height: 74px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 23px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: table;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .canvas-container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 1024px;
        min-width: 120px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>About Page template By Adobe Dreamweaver CC</title>
    <link href="AboutPageAssets/styles/aboutPageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
    <script>
        var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "dreamweaver"
    </script>
    <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/montserrat:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body onload="load();">
    <!-- Header content -->
    <header>
        <div class="profileLogo">
            <!-- Profile logo. Add a img tag in place of <span>. -->
            <p class="logoPlaceholder">
                <!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Name :</span></p>
            <p class="logoPlaceholder">
                <!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Attempts :</span></p>
            <p class="logoPlaceholder">
                <!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Score :</span></p>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="canvas-container">

                        <canvas id="main" width="500px" height="250px"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Links to Social network accounts -->
        <aside class="socialNetworkNavBar">
            <div id="left" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav">
                <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here -->
                <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75">

            </div>
            <div id="down" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav">
                <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here -->
                <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75"> </div>
            <div id="right" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav">
                <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here -->
                <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75">
            </div>

        </aside>
    </header>
    <!-- content -->

</body>

</html>
```

<sup>apology for not giving explanation</sup>

Comment: No sweat, i'll try to read the code and figure out the behaviors . Thanks mate !

Comment: Just a quick question, if i want to reset the position. Should I just create a new function like below :
`function reset(){
imgLoaded = true;
context.drawImage(img,250,0);
}`
Is it advisable like this, i want to trigger this like 10 seconds after input down is triggered. So i'll use the `setTimeout(reset,3000)`?

Comment: Yes it is. You should use `function reset() {
   if (!imgLoaded) return;
   context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
   context.drawImage(img, 250, 0);
}`

Comment: A last question, is it possible to bind hold function on onclick?

Comment: Yes, possible *(but, that's a diff. question)*